# How to write my own Haskell sortOn function

Tags: function, sorting, haskell, functional-programming, haskell-platform

I was wondering how to write my own `sortOn` function.

I made a `sortBy` function and an `on` function as shown bellow but can't figure out how to combine them and what additional code to add. `sortOn` is like `sortBy` but the given function (in here named `comp`) is applied only once for every element of the list

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
sortBy comp [] = []
sortBy comp [x] = [x]
sortBy comp (x:xs) = insert x (sortBy comp xs)
 where 
  insert x [] = [x]
  insert x (y:ys) 
   | (comp x y == LT) || (comp x y == EQ) = x:y:ys
   | otherwise = y:(insert x ys)

on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
on b f x y = b (f x) (f y)
```

Comment: [the standard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.

If you have a list `[a]` and you just `sort` it, the `sort` function will implicitly make use of the `Ord` instance for `a` and specifically the function:

```
compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
```

to figure out the relative ordering of pairs of `a` elements.

Now, if you have a list `[a]` **and** a transformation function `b`, and you want to use `sortOn` to sort the list of the transformed values, you'll need to figure out the relative ordering of pairs of `b` elements.  How will you do this?  Well, you'll implicitly use the `Ord` instance for `b` and specifically the function:

```
compare :: b -> b -> Ordering
```

In other words, when you try to define:

```
sortOn :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
sortOn f lst = ...
```

you'll have arguments of type:

```
f :: a -> b
lst :: [a]
```

and additional objects of type:

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
compare :: b -> b -> Ordering
```

Now, can you see how to put them together to define `sortOn`?

#### SPOILERS

Further hint:  What's the type of `` compare `on` f ``?

Further further hint:  It's `a -> a -> Ordering`.